# NoClassDefFoundError, OnLayoutChangeListener and Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I've read that `OnLayoutChangeListener` is not available under API Level 11. However, IDEA compiles this project successfully for 2.3.3 (but not for 2.2), and it crashes, of course. And I don't know even places where those caveats are hidden. It'll shot one day.

I'm using IDEA 12 EAP. Is it a bug? Should I ask the support?

Comment: According to the documentation, it was added in API Level 11 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html).

Comment: @JustinJasmann Yes, I've read that. The question is that Android sources are buggy or IDEA.

Comment: Hmm. How can you be compiling against 2.3.3 and have an OnLayoutChangeListener?

Comment: I agree, that shouldn't even compile via command-line. Doubt it's an issue with IDEA, more-so a messed up configuration file.